# Parallelize inner loops with streams when writing to outer variables

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I'm stuck on parallelizing the following code:

```
double[][] a, b, c;
double d;
double[] e;
for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    double f = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        double a1 = a[i-1][j];
        double a2 = a[i][j];
        double a3 = a1 * a2;
        d -= a3;
        c[i][j] = c[i - 1][j] + a3;
        f += c[i][j] * a3;
    }
    e[i] = d + f;
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        a[i][j] = e[i] * b[i][j]
    }
}
```

The second inner loop depends on the first (because of `e[i]`) so they must be executed sequentially, but within each of them, computation can be parallelized on `y`.

The problem is they both read and write on external variables. Writing can be parallelized (conceptually), because each inner loop aggregates its partial results to the global variables.

`x` is in the order of 10000 and `y` 250. Inner loops processing is simplified in this example but is actually more computationally intense.

The question here is how to parallelize loops that read and write external variables?

The following attempt doesn't compile because of `d` and `f`:

```
double[][] a, b, c;
double d;
double[] e;
for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    double f = 0.0;
    IntStream.range(0, y).parallel().forEach(j -> {  
        double a1 = a[i-1][j];
        double a2 = a[i][j];
        double a3 = a1 * a2;
        d -= a3;
        c[i][j] = c[i - 1][j] + a3;
        f += c[i][j] * a3;
    });
    e[i] = d + f;
    IntStream.range(0, y).parallel().forEach(j -> {  
        a[i][j] = e[i] * b[i][j];
    });
}
```

Comment: **Short Answer**: Just don't use parallel for this. The overhead is way to much than the actual benefit

Comment: Actual inner loops are far more heavy that what is shown. Please assume it makes sense to parallelize, like each loop on y takes 2 min for example.

Comment: Well then I can say. What have you tried? You have 1.4k reputation and still don't seem to understand what to ask here. Currently you have shown us code which works (fine) in the old way. But where are your attempts? Where do you struggle? Please clarify and edit your question. Because right now it is just. "Do the work for me please"

Comment: Also I don't really see any streams in your code. Do you want is to simply rewrite your code for you using Streams? Because I am quite sure you would be able to at least attempt that on your own

Comment: @Samuel can you please provide sample input and sample output, for `a,b,c,d`?

Comment: Looks like you can parallelize only outer loop.

Comment: @user1516873 Outer loop iterations depend on previous iterations (reads `a[i-1]` and writes `a[i]`, so it cannot be parallelized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parallelize the sub-loops, you have to understand first what is the result of each of them.

The result of the first loop is:

- the increment to variable `d`
- the value of `f`
- the new `c[i]` sub-array

To compute them, you can create a custom type to hold the 3 values, and then perform a mutable reduction to compute all the 3. For lack of a better name, I will call the custom type `ResultContainer`.

Similarly, the result of the second loop is the array `a[i]`. This is simpler as it is easy to build an array from a `Stream`.

This would thus give:

```
for (int i0 = 1; i0 < x; i0++) {
    final int i = i0; // tmp store as final for use in lambda
    ResultContainer result = IntStream.range(0, y).parallel()
            .collect(() -> new ResultContainer(y), (resultContainer, j) -> {
                double a1 = a[i - 1][j];
                double a2 = a[i][j];
                double a3 = a1 * a2;
                double cij = c[i - 1][j] + a3;
                resultContainer.add(-a3, cij * a3, j, cij);
            }, ResultContainer::add);

    d += result.d;
    e[i] = d + result.f;
    c[i] = result.ci;
    a[i] = IntStream.range(0, y).parallel().mapToDouble(j -> e[i] * b[i][j]).toArray();
}
```

with our custom type:

```
class ResultContainer {
    double d;
    double f;
    double[] ci;

    public ResultContainer(int y) {
        this.d = 0;
        this.f = 0;
        ci = new double[y];
    }

    public void add(double d, double f, int j, double cij) {
        this.d += d;
        this.f += f;
        ci[j] = cij;
    }

    public void add(ResultContainer resultContainer2) {
        d += resultContainer2.d;
        f += resultContainer2.f;
        for (int j = 0; j < ci.length; j++) {
            // note that one of the two is always 0 here
            ci[j] += resultContainer2.ci[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Didier L! Was converging to something similar, but you had it working before me. Well done!